# Spark Thirft Service not started in Hadoop with Azure Storage Blob configuration

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, azure-blob-storage, bigdata

We have Created a High availability hadoop cluster with default file system as azure blob storage instead of hdfs by following the link https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-azure/index.html

Hivethrift service where started successfully but spark thift service where not started. 
I can able to connect the spark-shell and connect with blob by referening the jar file hadoop-azure.jar but cannot start the thrift service.

Command used to start spark thrift server:
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2 --master yarn

Following are the error details.

```
17/04/26 10:19:32 INFO metastore: Connected to metastore.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while insta
ntiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$
$reflect(SparkSession.scala:981)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSessio
n.scala:110)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:109
)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.appl
y(SparkSession.scala:878)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$getOrCreate$5.appl
y(SparkSession.scala:878)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.sca
la:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.sca
la:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala
:230)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.sc
ala:878)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkSQLEnv$.init(SparkSQLEnv.
scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2$.main(HiveTh
riftServer2.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.HiveThriftServer2.main(HiveThr
iftServer2.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSub
mit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:738)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:18
7)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$
$reflect(SparkSession.scala:978)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.ap
ache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog':
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$inter
nal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:169)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.<init>(SharedState.scala:86
)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkS
ession.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$$anonfun$sharedState$1.apply(SparkS
ession.scala:101)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState$lzycompute(SparkSession
.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sharedState(SparkSession.scala:100)

        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.scala:
157)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState.<init>(HiveSessionState.sc
ala:32)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState$.org$apache$spark$sql$inter
nal$SharedState$$reflect(SharedState.scala:166)
        ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstruct
orAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingC
onstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(Is
olatedClientLoader.scala:264)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.s
cala:366)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.s
cala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.<init>(HiveExternalCata
log.scala:65)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating the resu
lt, check the original exception for details.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.jav
a:522)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.HiveClientImpl.<init>(HiveClientImpl
.scala:192)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: java.util.NoSuchElementExc
eption: An error occurred while enumerating the result, check the original excep
tion for details.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadat
a(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:1930)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.NativeAzureFileSystem.getFileStatus(Native
AzureFileSystem.java:1592)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1424)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(Sess
ionState.java:596)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(Sess
ionState.java:554)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.jav
a:508)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: An error occurred while enumerating
 the result, check the original exception for details.
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySe
gmentedIterator.java:113)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.StorageInterfaceImpl$WrappingIterator.hasN
ext(StorageInterfaceImpl.java:128)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureNativeFileSystemStore.retrieveMetadat
a(AzureNativeFileSystemStore.java:1909)
        ... 54 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: The server encountered
an unknown failure: OK
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(Stora
geException.java:178)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(Exe
cutionEngine.java:273)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.LazySegmentedIterator.hasNext(LazySe
gmentedIterator.java:109)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAware
ParserConfiguration cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConf
iguration
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.<init>(Unknown Sou
rce)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.Utility.getSAXParser(Utility.java:54
6)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.BlobListHandler.getBlobList(BlobList
Handler.java:72)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer$6.postProcessResp
onse(CloudBlobContainer.java:1253)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer$6.postProcessResp
onse(CloudBlobContainer.java:1217)
        at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(Exe
cutionEngine.java:148)
        ... 57 more
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://10.0.0.4:4040
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Interrupting monitor thread
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Shutting down all executors
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Asking each exec
utor to shut down
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO SchedulerExtensionServices: Stopping SchedulerExtensionSe
rvices
(serviceOption=None,
 services=List(),
 started=false)
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Stopped
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEnd
point stopped!
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint:
OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\labuser\
AppData\Local\Temp\2\spark-11c406ec-2c53-4042-b336-9d1164c3c6f9
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: Stopping azure-file-system metrics sys
tem...
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: azure-file-system metrics system stopp
ed.
17/04/26 10:19:33 INFO MetricsSystemImpl: azure-file-system metrics system shutd
own complete.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution to this yet?